# Floating Range with additional number in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, range

I make Wind direction enum and I want to make a range that catches all values between 2 numbers OR third one:

**number between (0.0 and 45.0) OR (360.0)**

```
enum class WindDirections(val description: String,val shortName : String, val range: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double>,val image: Int) {

// North
NORTH("N North", "N" ,(0.0..45.0), R.drawable.wind_north_red50),
NORTH_EAST("NE North-East", "NE" ,45.1..90.0, R.drawable.wind_north_east_red),
(... East, South, West etc)
NOT_FOUND ("", "-",-1.1..-1.0,0); // error one, now 360* is inside that
```

(...)

With these functions, I want to get enum class - WindDirections with the right value, based on given angle `windDirection: Double`. For example:

- The angle between 0 and 45 (0.0..45.0) returns WindDirections.North (Now want to make when its 360 to return same)
- The angle between 45.1 and 90 (45.1..90.0) returns WindDirections.NORTH_EAST

  ```
  companion object {
       fun getDescriptionStringByDouble(windDirection: Double): String {
           return getWindDirectionByDouble(windDirection).description
       }
       fun getShortDescriptionStringByDouble(windDirection: Double):String {
           return getWindDirectionByDouble(windDirection).shortName
       }
  ```

I want to get North for a range of 0..45 and also 360

```
fun getWindDirectionByDouble(windDirection: Double): WindDirections {
        return when (windDirection) {
            in NORTH.range -> NORTH //   number between (0.0 and 45.0) OR (360.0 need to accomplish that one, now it isn't)
            in NORTH_EAST.range -> NORTH_EAST //   45 and 90
            (... East, South, West etc)
            else -> NOT_FOUND // when angle is not between 0 and 359.9 (for now 360 is here)
```

Thank you in advance

## **EDIT:**

The way to accomplish that is to make when catching my special case for 360 in function getWindDirectionByDouble() like that in bellow, but I ask, is it possible to add 360 in the range of NORTH somehow. "(0.0..45.0) and (360.0)"

```
fun getWindDirectionByDouble(windDirection: Double): WindDirections {
    return when (windDirection) {
        360.0 -> NORTH // Like that one, i will return right WindDirections.NORTH
        in NORTH.range -> NORTH //   number between (0.0 and 45.0) OR (360.0 need to accomplish that one, now it isn't)
        in NORTH_EAST.range -> NORTH_EAST //   45 and 90
        (... East, South, West etc)
        else -> NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: So you want to check if windDirection is between 0 and 45 and, in that case, return the value, otherwise return 360, correct?

Comment: no, I want to detect when variable "windDirection: Double = 360", 360 to be in range of North enum range. Angle of 0 return enum NORTH, angle of 44 return enum of North

Comment: I have edited the question, to be more clear, sorry for that I was unclear about my task

Comment: This isn't worth an answer, but in addition to the existing answer, another approach to handling the multiple ranges for NORTH might be for the enum to store a list of ranges instead of a single range.  NORTH would be a list with two entries, and the others would have a list with a single entry.

Comment: Also: instead of duplicating all the checks in a `when()` block, it would be more elegant to to have one check that tested all the ranges in turn.  Note that `WindDirections.values` is an array of all your directions, so you can call e.g. `find()` on it.

Comment: @gidds thank you for good ideas for improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flaw in using a Double ClosedRange for this since it treats the start and end inclusively. You worked around that by using 45.1 for example, but then there are numbers like 45.05 that won't be in any of the ranges.

You could make your own type of range that treats the end as exclusive. And you could also design it to handle angles outside 0-360 by calculating the positive remainder (modulo).

```
data class AngleRange(val start: Double, val endExclusive: Double) {
    operator fun contains(value: Double) = 
        ((value % 360.0 + 360.0) % 360.0).let { it >= start && it < endExclusive }
}
```

Then you can fully cover the possible ranges using `AngleRange(0.0, 45.0)`, `AngleRange(45.0, 90.0)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that important note. I also can add multiple ranges